# Problem finding the proper syntax for a function serializable in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to save a few parametrized functions in a data structure for use at runtime. I want to be able to enter the parameters in the editor.

I excluded UnityEvent as I don't want to specify the gameobject that will be affected in the editor.

I come from python so my mind is thinking decorator, which is obviously not gonna work in C#. I'm quite sure delegates and maybe reflection or Actions will come into play but I just can't figure the syntax.

```
public interface IStuffInstantiatedInEditor {
    public abstract void Call(Transform transfo);
}

[Serializable]
public class EditorTranslate: IStuffInstantiatedInEditor {
    public Vector3 trans;

    public void Call(Transform transfo) {
        transfo.Translate(trans);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class EditorRotateAround: IStuffInstantiatedInEditor {
    public Vector3 point;
    public float angle;

    public void Call(Transform transfo) {
        transfo.RotateAround(point, Vector3.forward, angle);
    }
    
}

[Serializable]
public delegate void CallWrapper(Transform transfo);

[Serializable]
public class EditorDataStructure {
    public List<CallWrapper> wrappers;
}
```

Missing part is the link `CallWrapper wrap1 = EditorTranslate(vecEnteredInEditor).Call`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do this would be to use ScriptableObjects. Now interfaces won't work for this as they cannot be serialised, but you can make the same contract with abstract inheritance.

```
public abstract class StuffInstantiatedInEditor : ScriptableObject
{
    public abstract void Call(Transform transfo);
}
```

Then create subtypes of this

```
public class EditorTranslate: IStuffInstantiatedInEditor 
{
   ...
}
```

etc

Then you can provide these subtypes with a [CreateAssetMenu](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CreateAssetMenuAttribute.html) attribute like so

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "StuffInstantiatedInEditor/EditorTranslate")]
public class EditorTranslate: StuffInstantiatedInEditor 
{
   ...
}
```

You can then create instances of these which will live in your assets folder, and can be serialised into any scenes you need.

Finally, your collection of them can be

```
[Serializable]
public class EditorDataStructure 
{
    public List<StuffInstantiatedInEditor> wrappers;
}
```

Which will work as is, as ScriptableObjects are serialisable by defualt

Comment: Close enough to the behaviour I have in mind. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote in code and what you're trying to do are a bit backwards one to another. You don't need to overkill it using delegates, unless you want events. Reflection is also irrelevant here. It has a different purpose. Also, don't confuse delegates with c# event-actions and with UnityEvents.

The interface and its implementation is fine. To call them, you just use basic references of instances and method calling:

```
IStuffInstantiatedInEditor translateInterface; // default visibility is private
                                               // so make sure to set it explicitly if needed
translateInterface.Call();
```

Assigning it is done the same as you would any other variable, unless it's in a different class and thus, needs to be `internal` or `public`.

So class `MyClass1` that has this member and is created in `myCls`:

```
myCls.translateInterface = new EditorTranslate();
myCls.translateInterface.trans = Vector3.one;
myCls.translateInterface.Call();
```

Then you can just do the same for `EditorRotateAround`.

Just remember that `ScriptableObjects` and `MonoBehaviours` **DO NOT** get instantiated using `new ()`.

If you want to get pointers to other `Call()` functions belonging to other instances, that is not the best approach. Just add the objects to a list and call the `Call()` on each collection element.

Also note for this scenario, while it's an example, you could have just used an `abstract` class and push polymorphism downwards. If you don't want to "externalize" the code too much, polymorphism is my choice (but it's a personal one). Interfaces are best when inheritance gets in a way or certain "aspects" of a class vary, regardless of inheritance.

Comment: "What you wrote in code and what you're trying to do are a bit backwards one to another" Most definitely --' This solution doesn't have the behaviour I'm looking for, but thank you for the advise on instantiation time and abstract. I will use them.

Comment: You're welcome. But in fairness, this solution is what you asked for: how to use function pointers (aka delegates). You voted for an answer that suggests a different solution, method and approach to what you asked for. So maybe you should have asked how to approach your problem, rather than how to use a C# paradigm and vote an answer that has nothing to do with what you asked and wanted, but suits your needs. Not meaning to make it out as bad as it sounds, it's just that if you'd have asked for advice, I'd have given a proper solution. I just answered what your topic question said.

Comment: Following your comment, I edited the title to remove the function pointer mention to avoid misleading people. The rest of the question already follow the "what I want", "what I tried" schema. Problem was indeed with my approach.